# Take a photo and send it to a webserver with Android

Tags: android, json, base64

I must send a photo taked from device an send it to a webservice

The remote method that receive the images has this form

```
@Webservice(paramNames = {"id", "title", "fileBase64", "ext"}, description = "Add a receipt to the post.")
    public Response addReceipt(Integer id, String title, String fileBase64, String ext) throws Exception {
        User us = getUserLogged();
        PostService ps = new PostService();
        Post p = (Post) ps.read(idPost);
        if (us == null || !u.getUser().getId().equals(us.getId())) {
            return ErrorResponse.getIllegalOperationResponse(id, logger);
        }
        FileManager fm = new FileManager();
        String fileName = fm.saveReceipt(fileBase64, ext);
        PostReceipt pr = as.addReceipt(u, title, fileName);
        return new Response(new ReceiptJson(pr), null, id);
    }
```

So the problem is:

-how to take a photo

-how to encode the photo as base 64 to put it in the Json

```
{"id", "title", "fileBase64", "ext"}
```

that I must send to described method: